# indexing and searching within unix.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, search

I wanted to find if I have asked a question about disk-image, so I tried various permutations of `user:me tags [disk-image]` and `user:me type is:question tags [disk-image]` but failed to find any relevant results. I finally put up a question, [preparing a usb drive to be bootable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233485/preparing-a-usb-drive-to-be-bootable) and again tried to see but came up with the same result, i.e. no result.

Is there a delay in the site indexing the tags with user etc. or is the search broken someway or am I not doing it correctly, maybe there is a specific order in which the search pattern should be.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `[foo]` already searches for posts tagged with `foo`. That's what the `[ ]` do. You can find your question by searching for [`user:me [disk-image]`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A50490%20%5Bdisk-image%5D). Because you searched for `tags [disk-image]`, you actually searched for the string `tags` in questions tagged with `[disk-image]`.

This is explained on the [search help page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

> To search within specific tag(s), enter them in square brackets: [maintenance] seat searches for mentions of "seat" within the [maintenance] tag.

Comment: I did try also what you shared  `user:me \[disk-image]\` but that didn't went anywhere. I also tried  `user:me \[disk-image\] but also didn't get me anywhere. The difference as can be seen is in the positioning of the slash.

Comment: @shirish sorry, the slashes were added automatically by the markdown parser (apparently), there should be no slashes. Try clicking on the search link in my (updated) answer (which uses your user id instead of `user:me` but should run the same search) or write `user:me [disk-image]`.

Comment: for some reason, now it works but before the same thing didn't, :confused: